# Can AWS SNS be used to sent voice messages to landline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We were using Amazon SNS to send SMS to our end-user. But now, we also need to sent our end users voice messages over landline.

Is it something feasible with Amazon SNS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, we are unable to send voice message through AWS SNS.

But you might be interested in Amazon pinpoint which allows you to send voice messages through that api, check [here](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/pricing/) for pricing and to get started